# How to show real url on the navigation bar when using <a href="#" onclick="funtion('test.php')">

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I tried to open the content pages in  using a javascript. So, I don't have to write all the header and footer pages. However, there is a problem, the url is not show in the navigation bar. Are there anyway to make the real url show up in the navigation bar? http://www.page.com/test.php?

```js
<script>
 function openLink(url) {

  $( ".contentTable" ).load(url);
   
 }
</script>
```

```html
<a id="link1" href="#" onclick="openLink('test.php')">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use the history api of your browser :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

An example :

```
history.pushState({}, "New page test", "/test.php");
```

First param is a state, second one a title and the third one your url.

pushState will add the entry to your history and replaceState will replace your current history state by a new one.